# Webpart is not changing when i change ascx file

Tags: web-part

I've just installed custom webpart from `.wsp` with html in `ascx` file and it works good. But when I want to update .`ascx` content then it is not changing even after retracting/iisreset/rain dance/voodoo ceremony - any ideas?

Comment: how are you testing this ?

Comment: just added some <p>This is testline </p> to .ascx  - it is not displayed, earlier tried to import js files but this also failed :/

Comment: I hope you are following steps,  after modifying. ascx file.  Redeploy the webpart.  Clear browse cache.  And add Web part and then testing the changes. ??

Comment: Please retract solution and remove solution, remove the web part in Web Part section in Site setting. Test webpart available or not by inserting this webpart in page. After checking it, add and deploy this solution again.

Comment: Such problems have really few chances to happen if you update (or uninstall/reinstall) your updated WSP package... Could you double-check?

Comment: Are you developing this web part or you just have wsp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After deploying solution, Go to site collection features and then deactivate the feature related to that web-part and activate again.

Sometimes I faced this issue, feature deactivation-activation helps me to resolve the issue.

Comment: IMO there's no chance a feature activation/deactivation solves such a problem: a Web part is a piece of code that sits both in the \14 hive and in a DLL (probably in the GAC). Activating a feature never impacts such system files.

Comment: Hi Evariste, It may be not happened to you. But this happens to us 2 -3 times and feature activation/deactivation helped us.

Answer (score 3):

If it's VS 2012 web part (not for farm level) there will be one g.cs file in web part. I am talking about in VS. whenever you make any changes in html it will update as well, sometimes it's not update when we made changes to ascx file.

so in your case g.cs file is updating there are two solutions.

1. if it's not too much update you can manually change the g.cs. i know it's little bit hard because of XML.
2. In VS there are option to recreate it again by run custom tool.